# On Change Not Getting Fired In Vue Template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I’m a newbie in Vue. I’ve created a form component which includes a select. I want to use a custom function when this select changed. I’ve searched in this forum and in the web also and I tried lots of codes, but the function didn’t fired. Here is my form template:

```
<template>

<form method="post" action="/Home/Register">

    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-title">

            <label for="EventId">
                Choose *
            </label>

        </div>

        <div class="form-input">

            <select class="form-control" name="EventId" id="EventId" @change="onSelectChange">
                <option value="" disabled>Please Select...</option>
                <option :value="item.Id" :data-price="item.EventPrice" v-for="item in model.Events">{{ item.EventName }}</option>
            </select>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="row" style="justify-content: center;">

            <button class="btn btn-success">
                Register
            </button>

        </div>

    </div>


</form>
```

Script tag for template:

```
export default {
        props: ["model"],
        methods: {
            onSelectChange : function(event) {
                console.log(event);
            }
        }
    }
```

I’ve also tried v-model for select but no luck. I’ve put a breakpoint inside the generated js code by vue in Chrome, “change” function isn’t getting triggered.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks,

## Update

I'm grateful for all of the answers and comments, but I need to explain **this issue is for only "Vue Template" files**. I have a "RegistryForm.vue" template file and I'm building this file with webpack. I need to get selected option value when it changed **in this template file**. My "onSelectChange" event doesn't triggered and still I'm searching for the solution. These template files were the most important reason for choosing Vue as Javascript framework for us. And if we can't fix this problem, we should develop our system from scratch with another framework.

Thanks for helping again.

Comment: You should use v-on:change="onSelectChange"

Comment: Seems ok, can you provide a live example in JSFiddle or else)?

Comment: @gugateider Tried, but it didn't worked.

Comment: why do you need that event?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i need this because i want to make a calculation according to selected option and show that calculation in my register form. And this form should be a Vue template (.vue file).

Comment: @SajibKhan I can't just paste it to jsfiddle because this is a template and needs to get built with webpack but I've pasted the created javascript file after build: https://jsfiddle.net/9bmfxk4g/ I hope it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: it's not helpful, need to debug your vue codes... see if you create a demo like https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/

Comment: @SajibKhan that's what I'm saying these aren't template samples, you cannot create a runnable template sample on jsfiddle because it has to be compiled with npm. There isn't any problem when I work on html file with Vue. But I need a solution with a seperate template file.

Answer (score 1):

try passing the event to your `onSelectChange` method.
this works for me:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Register">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-title">
            <label for="EventId">
                Choose *
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <select class="form-control" name="EventId" id="EventId" @change="onSelectChange($event)"> 
                <option value="" disabled>Please Select...</option>
                <option :value="item.Id" :data-price="item.EventPrice" v-for="item in model.Events" >{{ item.EventName }}</option>
            </select>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="row" style="justify-content: center;">

            <button class="btn btn-success">
                Register
            </button>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for help. I've tried your code in my template but it didn't worked.

Comment: There isn't any problem when I work on html file with Vue. But I need a solution with a seperate template file. I have "RegistryForm.vue" template file and I'm building this file with webpack.

Comment: that means something is wrong with the way you create your component. its slightly different than creating simple vue instance. make sure you have data property, and its a function. read more: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html